# How do I redirect a User to the app when opening a link in Safari?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I want to redirect Users to my iOS application when they type a specific domain (one I control) in to the address bar.

I have my `apple-app-site-association` file:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "TEAM_ID.bundle_identifier",
        "paths": [ "*" ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is uploaded to my server running HTTPS, sitting inside of a `.well-known` directory in the root of my server.

On XCode, I have linked the `Associated Domains` and just added `applinks:example.com` (for now).

When I email myself the link and click it, my application opens perfectly. How do I extend it further to allow the app to open when clicking on a link in Safari?

I want to enable a sharing mechanism whereby a User clicks a link on Twitter Mobile Web (for example) and my application opens.

Edit: I've got URL Types set up but of course it requires a User/site to redirect to example:// - this isn't what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Safari should handle Universal Links but they have a limitation of opening the app when you are already on the same domain. For example, if you are on `example.com` and click on a Universal Link `example.com/deep/link/path`. It will stay on the browser.

This is why [Branch](http://docs.branch.io) uses 2 URLs. `example.app.link` and `example-alternate.app.link` so when you click on a link when already on the website you are still taken to the app.

Also, **typing** a Universal Link into Safari does not work. **It must be tapped.**